# Web scraping price with the use of xml

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

I am trying to **scrape** the following: 13.486 Kč  from: https://www.aofis.cz/informace-pro-klienty/elba-opf/

For some reason, the following code does not seem to find the number. I am rather a newbie to this so perhaps it is because the string in xml_find_all is wrong. Can anyone please have a look why?

```
library(xml)
library(xml2)

page <- "https://www.aofis.cz/informace-pro-klienty/elba-opf/"  
read_page <- read_html(page)

Price <- read_page %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes('page-content') %>%
  xml2::xml_find_all("//strong[contains(@class 'sg_selected')]") %>% 
  rvest::html_text()

Price
```

Thank you!!
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html code you see in your browser developer panel (or selector gadget) is not the same as the content that is being delivered to your R session. It is actually a javascript file which then builds the web page. This is why your `rvest` call isn't finding the correct html node: *there are no html nodes in the string you are processing*!

There are a few different ways to get the information you want, but perhaps the best is to just get the monetary values from the javascript code using regex:

```r
page <- "https://www.aofis.cz/informace-pro-klienty/elba-opf/"  
read_page <- httr::content(httr::GET(page), "text")
stringr::str_extract_all(read_page, "\\d+\\.\\d+ K")[[1]][1]
#> [1] "13.486 K"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Allan Cameron! Indeed! Very helpful!!!